# How to create Bar Chart using KendoUI based on web service

Tags: kendo-ui

I am a beginner in KendoUI. I want to display a Bar Chart using Kendo UI in my mobile application(based on Phone Gap). The data for this Bar Chart should come from a web service. This web service returns data in the form of JSON object having JSON array of X and Y co-ordinates.

I tried this

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: " some URL ",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        sort: {
            field: "year",
            dir: "asc"
        }
    }
});
```

Any help will be very useful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.Net Web API will be your best buddy to create HTTP services returning JSON. Check this tutorial: http://docs.kendoui.com/tutorials/ASP.NET/asp-net-hello-services